# How to convert the xml file in a nsdictionary format in iphone if tag name is unknown

Tags: iphone, ios, xml

How to convert the xml file in a nsdictionary format in iphone if tag name is unknown so i can reuse this file all time whenever i want to convert xml to nsdictionary format...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [this and it works pretty well](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/09/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/). Had issues when there is only a single tag, but i guess you will figure out the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a Generic XML parser for it. Make a Generic XML parser for your xml file

Comment: Try this http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml and implement GDataXML.